# Service not avaliable Unity3d error in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, dependencies, shared-library, unity3d

I'm trying to use [Unity3d](https://unity3d.com/es) in Kubuntu, but I'm getting this error:

```
Service not avaliable, please try again later.
```

I've found [this post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/):

```
Certain systems may experience "Service unavailable" errors when trying to log in. WORKAROUND: Launch Unity with LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 /path/to/Unity (check the path to your local libresolv)
```

I've checked the path of libresolv.so.2 in my computer. I found it under /lib32/libresolv.so.2 and under /libx32/libresolv.so.2. (Don't know what the difference is).

When I run:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib32/libresolv.so.2 /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity
```

I get:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib32/libresolv.so.2' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

and when I run:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/libx32/libresolv.so.2 /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity
```

I get:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/libx32/libresolv.so.2' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

With both commands I also get this:

```
/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity: /opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Tools/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the same command with this other path:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
```

And now it works. Hope it will be useful for someone!

(I still don't know why I have this lib repeated so much, I suppose they are different compilations, for 32, 64 bits, aren't they?)

Comment: Same problem and same solution on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!