# Unity3d not logging in

Tags: package-management, software-installation, unity3d

I recently installed Unity3d for Ubuntu with the `.deb` file I found [there](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/unity3d-linux-build), but on launch I am not able to connect to my account:, and I get this error:

```
Service not availabe, please try again later.
```

[image: Buggy Unity3d]

on the red stripe, after clicking the`Sign In` button.
I then launched Unity3d from a terminal, and I saw an error description that maybe is the cause to my problem:

[image: error descr]

I tried to reinstall `libgcrypt20` and `libgpg-error0` that seem to be the faulty packages but nothing worked.

I even redownloaded the `.deb` package, and checked both md5 sums, which turned out to be dentical, so I guess the problem is not the package itself.

What is wrong with it then?

Answer (score 0):

Actually that question has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786449/486358).
try:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 /path/to/Unity
```

where `/path/to/Unity` is likely to be `/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity`

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution. I have marked your question as a dupe.